# L-value interpretation of overloading operator()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

While studying graph theory, I wanted to try some code, so I came up with this:

```
class edge
{
public:
    edge(char v1, char v2, int wt = INT_MAX) : vertex1(v1), vertex2(v2), weight(wt) {}

    edge(const edge& e)
    {
        this->vertex1 = e.vertex1;
        this->vertex2 = e.vertex2;
        this->weight = e.weight;
    }

    edge& operator=(const edge& e)
    {
        this->weight = e.weight;
        return *this;
    }

    edge& operator=(const int& w)
    {
        this->weight = w;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const edge& e) const
    {
        const auto res = this->weight == e.weight;
        return res;
    }

    bool is_connected() const { return !(weight == INT_MAX); }

    char    vertex1;
    char    vertex2;
    int     weight;
};
```

And corresponding `graph` class:

```
class graph
{
public:
    edge operator ()(const char &i, const char &j) const;  // #1
    edge& operator ()(const char &i, const char &j);  // #2
    // More implementations...

private:
    std::vector<char>   vertices;
    std::vector<edge>   edges;
};
```

This allows me to write code like this:

```
graph g;
g('a', 'b') = 1;
g('a', 'f') = 2;

g('a', 'b') = g('a', 'f');  // #2 is called
g('a', 'b');    // #2 is called
```

How can I cause `#1` to get called? Okay, also it occurs to me that something might be wrong with this construct. Could someone kindly review this code for me? Thanks!
Also, I read this one [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op), but I need more information.

Comment: The appropriate place for the code review portion is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The `const` qualifier is so the function can be called on `const` objects.

Comment: Is it a problem that #2 is called instead of #1?

Comment: The function is determined based on type, not on value category.

Comment: Correct me, if wrong but I thought that the 'const' on the right was meant to say that this function shall not attempt to modify any of the member variables. It can well be called on any type of objects, const or not.
Other question, say this function did different things: assignment or creation vs indexing(only if exists) this might be a problem. Also, always be absolutely certain of what your code would do, never leave it on implementation.

Comment: You should not have the const and non-const versions of a function do vastly different things. If one returns a reference, the other should probably return a const reference. Having the non-const version insert something and the non-const version just indexing is very confusing and error-prone. That's why `std::map` only has non-const `operator[]` for example.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: I guess it depends on your definition of "vastly" -- IMO its OK to have the const version throw an exception if a modification would be required, but do the same as the non-const version if no insertion/modification is needed.  This constitutes "sufficiently similar" in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this sort of thing, you need to have your `operator()` return an `edge_ref` helper object that can be assigned to (to insert an edge into the graph), or implicitly converted into an `edge`:

```
class graph {
    std::set<char>                        vertices;
    std::map<std::pair<char, char>, int>  edges;
    class edge_ref {
        graph &self;
        char i, j;
     public:
        edge_ref(graph &g, char i, char j): self(g), i(i), j(j) {}
        int operator=(int weight) {
            self.vertices.insert(i);
            self.vertices.insert(j);
            return self.edges[std::make_pair(i, j)] = weight; }
        operator int() {
            return self.edges.at(std::make_pair(i, j)); }
    };
 public:
    edge_ref operator()(char i, char j) { return edge_ref(*this, i, j); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Overload resolution between these two methods is roughly equivalent to the overload resolution of the following two functions.

```
edge  func(const graph *thiz, const char &i, const char &j);  // #1
edge& func(graph *thiz, const char &i, const char &j);  // #2
```

then the following call is fully matched with the #2 because the first argument is not `const`.

```
graph g;
func(&g, 'a', 'b');
```

However if the first argument was `const`, only #1 can be called.

Comment: I got your answer now! :)